# Use the secant method to approximate $\sin^{-1}(0.1)$ correct to 3 decimal

Tags: analysis

Use the secant method to approximate $\sin^{-1}(0.1)$ correct to $3$ decimal places starting with $x_0 = 0$ and $x_1 = 0.1$.

Comment: Please indicate what you've tried and what you understand about the problem so that people can give relevant help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that we are trying to approximate numerically the smallest positive root of the equation $\sin x=0.1$.

Equivalently, we are solving numerically the equation $f(x)=0$, where 
$$f(x)=\sin x -0.01.$$
Now run the machinery of the secant method, using $x_0=0$, and $x_1=0.1$. Presumably your book or notes tell you how to write down the appropriate recurrence formula for $x_{n+1}$ in terms of $x_n$ and $x_{n-1}$.

If your book or notes fail to do that, there is a good description of the [Secant Method in Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method)

As a check on the work you will do, my calculation gave $x_2\approx 0.1001669$. We might as well as well stop there.

Actually, we could have just done nothing, since the $0.1$ we were given is already correct to $3$ decimal places.

If your course expects a formal check that your answer $a$ is close enough, you can evaluate $f(a\pm 0.0005)$. and show there is a sign change.

Comment: thanks, it is a great help for me that i can understand...

Comment: You are welcome. My answer was short because the Wikipedia article is pretty good. If there is detail you need, just ask.